# Allocating "weak" memory pages

Tags: c, caching, memory, memory-management, virtual-memory

I am interested to know if there is a way to allocate "weak" memory in userspace in common operating systems like Linux, OS X, or Windows (obviously not possible with standard interfaces). What I mean is the sort of an `mmap()`, which would invalidate the mapping if the OS elects to push the pages out of core.

Say, I want to work with a 10G dataset on a 32-bit system. To get a piece from this dataset, I read it from the file and decompress it to memory[. I would prefer to keep the decompressed versions of the pieces around, if possible, to avoid decompressing the data on each access, but to allow accessing all pieces I must eventually free some data to avoid exhausting the memory/address space.

I can emulate this by gluing a framework on top of `malloc()` to free the old pieces if `malloc()` `NULL`s out, but it deprives other processes of memory and makes them to page out (or pages out the decompressed pieces). Or, I could keep some soft limit in the application, but that seems arbitrary and only alleviates the problem, and is suboptimal if there's free memory around. I feel that this is something that a virtual memory manager in a modern OS should handle.

Any tips and information about how this problem is tackled in other modern applications are appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to build a cache system?

Comment: I would prefer to exploit the caching built in the operating system already, maybe using platform-specific system calls

Comment: How is this different from the paging every modern OS already does?

Comment: If I understand correctly how paging works, in this scenario I never want the OS to save my pages to disk (and re-read them), but to signal me that they have been discarded

Comment: But *why* would you not want the OS to save and restore the free'd pages when you need them again? Since you've done "some [...] nontrivial processing" on them, why would you want to do it again?

Comment: Decompressing the original data is likely faster than reading/writing the uncompressed pages (I have edited the question to remove this confusion)

Comment: "likely faster" is not a good start for this sort of complexity. I'd strongly recommend building a testcase and doing some benchmarks. Otherwise this is premature optimization.

Comment: I have a 2.5GB dataset of GIF images comprising map tiles of a country. I decompress some to build a full screen local map, which I can drag by mouse or step by keyboard. I don't `malloc` or `free` the resource, but allocate a fixed size array for decompressed images, which includes information of recent usage. When I need one, I check if it is buffered, if not, I overwrite the oldest with a new decompressed image. I record the frame number of recent usage. The "drag response" after implementing this was dramatic. I set its memory requirement to not cripple other apps.

Comment: AIX has `SIGDANGER` for this, but in general, you don't want to operate like this.

Comment: @EOF at my current setup, LZ4 can decompress about 1G/s and achieve a compression ratio of about 1/2, so with 100M/s disk reads (out of cache) decompressing 1G from disk is about 11s and reading uncompressed is 20s; you might be totally right that this is a premature optimization, but I am interested if there are better solutions

Comment: @FUZxxl Thank you for this information, even though it is unlikely to help me!

Comment: @FUZxxl Why don't you want to operate like this? The kernel does it! (for disk caches)

Comment: @immibis The kernel is special in that it knows about how the kernel manages space. The kernel page cache also employs algorithms that divide free space up between different file systems in a fair manner. That's not possible with your approach, your program would just completely kill the file system cache and likely cause swapping (the kernel starts swapping long before memory is full). It would be better if your program had an option “how much memory for cache” and managed that pool itself.

Comment: This reminds me to a futile discussion I had with another user on SU. http://superuser.com/a/789551/93003  Unfortunately the kernel doesn't help you to solve this problem so you have to write your own stuff and constantly monitor the system. Quite sad.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no mechanism in common operating systems that implement the weak userspace memory as you describe.

Weak references come from the domain of garbage collection frameworks where an object/allocation is otherwise abandoned (i.e. has no "strong" references).  The weak references will be invalidated/nulled if the garbage collector gets to the allocation before the application attempts to recycle it by assigning the weak reference to a "strong" one.

The functionality you describe in your question and in the subsequent comments could be better and more simply implemented by an application cache that discards "pages" when he cache fills up and overwrites them with newly needed "pages".  Be careful to implement mutexes if the cache can be accessed by multiple threads.  The mutexes (if needed) are the most exotic thing here.  Everything else is pretty standard vanilla programming.

By way of an academic exercise, you could implement the concept you are describing at the kernel level with a device driver meaning the capability would be exposed as a pseudo device.  I would be very reluctant to acutally base a production implementation on this pseudo device as it has a negative effect on portability and maintainability, could adversely affect the entire platform's performance and behavior (after all we're talking kernel code here), and would by comparison take a long time to develop and test.

Good luck in your endeavor.